# What is the difference between map() and switchMap() methods?

Tags: android, android-architecture-components, android-livedata

What is the difference between those 2 methods of the LiveData class? The official doc and tutorial are pretty vague on that. In the **map()** method the first parameter called **source** but in the **switchMap()** it called **trigger**. What's the rationale behind that?

Answer (score 110, accepted):

As per the documentation

[Transformations.map()](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/Transformations#map(androidx.lifecycle.LiveData%3CX%3E,%20androidx.arch.core.util.Function%3CX,%20Y%3E))

> Applies a function on the value stored in the LiveData object, and propagates the result downstream.

[Transformations.switchMap()](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/Transformations#switchMap(androidx.lifecycle.LiveData%3CX%3E,%20androidx.arch.core.util.Function%3CX,%20androidx.lifecycle.LiveData%3CY%3E%3E))

> Similar to map, applies a function to the value stored in the LiveData object and unwraps and dispatches the result downstream. **The function passed to switchMap() must return a LiveData object**.

In other words, I may not be 100% correct but if you are familiar with RxJava; `Transformations#map` is kind of similar to `Observable#map` & `Transformations#switchMap` is similar to `Observable#switchMap`.

Let's take an example, there is a LiveData which emits a string and we want to display that string in capital letters.

One approach would be as follows; in an activity or fragment

```
Transformations.map(stringsLiveData, String::toUpperCase)
    .observe(this, textView::setText);
```

the function passed to the `map` returns a string only, but it's the `Transformation#map` which ultimately returns a `LiveData`.

The second approach; in an activity or fragment

```
Transformations.switchMap(stringsLiveData, this::getUpperCaseStringLiveData)
            .observe(this, textView::setText);

private LiveData<String> getUpperCaseStringLiveData(String str) {
    MutableLiveData<String> liveData = new MutableLiveData<>();
    liveData.setValue(str.toUpperCase());
    return liveData;
}
```

If you see `Transformations#switchMap` has actually switched the `LiveData`. So, again as per the documentation **The function passed to switchMap() must return a LiveData object**.

So, in case of `map` it is the **source** `LiveData` you are transforming and in case of `switchMap` the passed `LiveData` will act as a **trigger** on which it will switch to another `LiveData` after unwrapping and dispatching the result downstream.

Comment: That would explain the naming. So they both supposed to be triggered every time the underlying LiveData changes and "switch" means that LiveData is going to be switched to another LiveData object. Thanks!

Comment: Nice explanation - I've added an example of a combination of a switchMap and Map on my repo..  https://github.com/febaisi/ListenableWorkerExample/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/febaisi/listenableworkerexample/ui/MainViewModel.kt ..
'SwitchMap' is used just to listen to a button event and switch to the proper LiveData which is a Map of a Worker result. I hope it helps too.

Comment: Both Transformations(map, switchMap) returns the LiveData objects.

Answer (score 49):

My observation is that, if your transformation process is fast (Doesn't involve database operation, or networking activity), then you can choose to use `map`.

However, if your transformation process is slow (Involving database operation, or networking activity), you need to use `switchMap`

### `switchMap` is used when performing time-consuming operation

```
class MyViewModel extends ViewModel {
    final MutableLiveData<String> mString = new MutableLiveData<>();
    final LiveData<Integer> mCode;


    public MyViewModel(String string) {

        mCode = Transformations.switchMap(mString, input -> {
            final MutableLiveData<Integer> result = new MutableLiveData<>();

            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // Pretend we are busy
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(5000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    int code = 0;
                    for (int i=0; i<input.length(); i++) {
                        code = code + (int)input.charAt(i);
                    }

                    result.postValue(code);
                }
            }).start();

            return result;
        });

        if (string != null) {
            mString.setValue(string);
        }
    }

    public LiveData<Integer> getCode() {
        return mCode;
    }

    public void search(String string) {
        mString.setValue(string);
    }
}
```

### `map` is not suitable for time-consuming operation

```
class MyViewModel extends ViewModel {
    final MutableLiveData<String> mString = new MutableLiveData<>();
    final LiveData<Integer> mCode;


    public MyViewModel(String string) {

        mCode = Transformations.map(mString, input -> {
            /* 
                Note: You can't launch a Thread, or sleep right here. 
                If you do so, the APP will crash with ANR.
            */
            /*
            try {
                Thread.sleep(5000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            */

            int code = 0;
            for (int i=0; i<input.length(); i++) {
                code = code + (int)input.charAt(i);
            }
            return code;
        });

        if (string != null) {
            mString.setValue(string);
        }
    }

    public LiveData<Integer> getCode() {
        return mCode;
    }

    public void search(String string) {
        mString.setValue(string);
    }
}
```

Comment: Simple and clear response, most response just explain again and again how it work internally, but the first thing I care for is why I would use it, without needing to understand it internal behaviour. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the time-consuming operation part, that makes lots of sense. However, it's still confusing to me that the same result could be done without using Transformations. For example, inside `search` function, I can run the time-consuming operation(only the thread part in the your example) and at the end call `mCode.postValue(code);` Is there any scenario I will have to use `switchMap` only?

Comment: @DinoTw We do not want to perform time-consuming operation with the `search` function, or launch a user thread within `search` function. That's why we introduce `LiveData`.

Answer (score 37):

First of all, `map()` and `switchMap()` methods are both invoked on the main thread. And they have nothing to do with being used for fast or slow tasks. However, it might cause lags on UI if you do complex computational or time consuming tasks inside these methods instead of a worker thread, parsing or converting a long and/or complex json response for instance, since they are executed on the UI thread.

- **map()**

map() method's code is

```
@MainThread
public static <X, Y> LiveData<Y> map(@NonNull LiveData<X> source,
        @NonNull final Function<X, Y> func) {
    final MediatorLiveData<Y> result = new MediatorLiveData<>();
    result.addSource(source, new Observer<X>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(@Nullable X x) {
            result.setValue(func.apply(x));
        }
    });
    return result;
}
```

What it does is, it uses a source LiveData, I is input type,  and calls setValue(O) on LiveData where O is output type.

For it to be clear let me give an example. You wish to write user name and last name to textView whenever a user changes.

```
  /**
     * Changes on this user LiveData triggers function that sets mUserNameLiveData String value
     */
    private MutableLiveData<User> mUserLiveData = new MutableLiveData<>();

    /**
     * This LiveData contains the data(String for this example) to be observed.
     */
    public final LiveData<String> mUserNameLiveData;
```

now let's trigger changes on mUserNameLiveData's String when mUserLiveData changes.

```
   /*
     * map() method emits a value in type of destination data(String in this example) when the source LiveData is changed. In this example
     * when a new User value is set to LiveData it trigger this function that returns a String type
     *         
     *              Input, Output
     * new Function<User, String>
     *
     *  public String apply(User input) { return output;}
     */

    // Result<Output>                        Source<Input>               Input, Output
    mUserNameLiveData = Transformations.map(mUserLiveData, new Function<User, String>() {
        @Override
        public String apply(User input) {
            // Output
            return input.getFirstName() + ", " + input.getLastName();
        }
    });
```

And let's do the same thing with `MediatorLiveData`

```
 /**
     * MediatorLiveData is what {@link Transformations#map(LiveData, Function)} does behind the scenes
     */
    public MediatorLiveData<String> mediatorLiveData = new MediatorLiveData<>();
    /*
     * map() function is actually does this
     */
    mediatorLiveData.addSource(mUserLiveData, new Observer<User>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(@Nullable User user) {
            mediatorLiveData.setValue(user.getFirstName() + ", " + user.getLastName());
        }
    });
```

And if you observe MediatorLiveData on Activity or Fragment you get the same result as observing `LiveData<String> mUserNameLiveData`

```
userViewModel.mediatorLiveData.observe(this, new Observer<String>() {
    @Override
    public void onChanged(@Nullable String s) {
        TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.textView2);

        textView.setText("User: " + s);

        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "User: " + s, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

- **switchMap()**

switchMap() returns the same MediatorLiveData not a **new** LiveData every time the SourceLiveData changes.

It's source code is

```
@MainThread
public static <X, Y> LiveData<Y> switchMap(@NonNull LiveData<X> trigger,
                                           @NonNull final Function<X, LiveData<Y>> func) {

    final MediatorLiveData<Y> result = new MediatorLiveData<>();

    result.addSource(trigger, new Observer<X>() {
        LiveData<Y> mSource;

        @Override
        public void onChanged(@Nullable X x) {
            LiveData<Y> newLiveData = func.apply(x);
            if (mSource == newLiveData) {
                return;
            }
            if (mSource != null) {
                result.removeSource(mSource);
            }
            mSource = newLiveData;
            if (mSource != null) {
                result.addSource(mSource, new Observer<Y>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onChanged(@Nullable Y y) {
                        result.setValue(y);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
    return result;
}
```

Basically what it does is, it creates a final MediatorLiveData and it's set to the Result like map does() but this time function returns LiveData

```
   public static <X, Y> LiveData<Y> map(@NonNull LiveData<X> source,
                                         @NonNull final Function<X, **Y**> func) {

        final MediatorLiveData<Y> result = new MediatorLiveData<>();

        result.addSource(source, new Observer<X>() {

            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable X x) {
                result.setValue(func.apply(x));
            }

        });

        return result;
    }

    @MainThread
    public static <X, Y> LiveData<Y> switchMap(@NonNull LiveData<X> trigger,
                                               @NonNull final Function<X, **LiveData<Y>**> func) {

        final MediatorLiveData<Y> result = new MediatorLiveData<>();

        result.addSource(trigger, new Observer<X>() {
            LiveData<Y> mSource;

            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable X x) {
                LiveData<Y> newLiveData = func.apply(x);
                if (mSource == newLiveData) {
                    return;
                }
                if (mSource != null) {
                    result.removeSource(mSource);
                }
                mSource = newLiveData;
                if (mSource != null) {
                    result.addSource(mSource, new Observer<Y>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onChanged(@Nullable Y y) {
                            result.setValue(y);
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });
        return result;
    }
```

So `map()` takes `LiveData<User>` and transforms it into a `String`, if `User` object changes name field changes for instance.

`switchMap()` takes a String and gets `LiveData<User>` using it. Query a user from web or db with a String and get a `LiveData<User>` as a result.

Comment: Great answer !!

Answer (score 27):

There are already some good answers above, but I still struggled with them till I understood it, so I will try to explain on a concrete example for people with my way of thinking, without going into technical details and code.

In both **`map`** and **`switchMap`** there is a **source** (or trigger) live data, and in both cases you want to **transform** it to another **live data**. Which one will you use - depends on the task that your transformation is doing.

### **`map`**

Consider the same simple example that is used everywhere - your **source** live data contains a `User` object - `LiveData<User>`, which points to the currently logged in user. You want to display a text in your UI saying `Current user: <USERNAME>`. In this case each change signal from source should trigger exactly one signal of the resulting "mapped" `LiveData`. For example, the current `User` object is "Bob" then the UI text shows `Current user: Bob`. Once your `LiveData<User>` triggers a change your UI will observe it and update text to `Current user: Alice`. Very simple, linear, one to one change.

### **`switchMap`**

Consider the following example - you want to create a UI which shows the users whose name matches the given search term. We can be quite smart about it and hold the search term as a LiveData! So it will be a `LiveData<String>` and every time the user inputs a new query string our `Fragment`/`Activity` will simply set the text input value to this live data in the `ViewModel`. As a result, this live data will fire a change signal. Once we get this signal we start searching for the users. Now let's consider our search is so fast that it immediately returns a value. At this point you think that you can just use a **`map`** and return the matching users which will update the UI. Well, you will have a bug now - imagine you update the database regularly and after next update more users appear matching the search term! As you can see, in this scenario the source trigger (search term) does not necessarily result in a single trigger of mapped live data, the mapped live data given to the UI might still need to continue triggering the values after new users are added to the database. At this point you might say, that we could return a "smarter" live data, which will not only wait for source triggers, but will also monitor the database for users matching the given term (you will be able to do that with `Room` DB out of the box). But then comes another question - what if the search term changes? So your term was `x`, it triggered a live data which queries the users and keeps an eye on the database, it returns `userx, userxx` and then after five minutes it returns `userx, userxxx` and so on. Then the term was changed to `y`. Now we need to somehow stop listening to the smart live data giving us users with `x` in it, and **switch** it with the new smart live data which will monitor and give us users with `y` in their names. And that is exactly what **`switchMap`** is doing! And notice, this switch needs to be done in such a way, that in your UI you just write `switchMap(...).observe` once, that means that `switchMap` must return a wrapper `LiveData` which will stay the same throughout the execution, but will **switch** the live data sources under the hood for us.

### Conclusion

Although they seem to look the same at first glance, the use cases for **`map`** and **`switchMap`** are different, you will get the feeling of which one to use once you start implementing your case, mostly when you realize that in you mapping function you have to call some code from your other modules (like `Repositories`) which return `LiveData`.

Comment: great explanation. I got a clear picture regarding differences but what would be the issue if we use the 'map' instead of 'switchmap' to get user object when searched for user and wrap it in the same livedata everytime. why do we need to change the livedata instance itself when querying for new user? @frangulyan

Comment: @HariKiran because the result of a single user search is dynamic, it changes over time, that's why it is a live data. So imagine you call `val searcResultLiveData = database.getFirstUserMatching("alice")` and start listening to search result changes for "alice". Then you need map it to the string "Found: <username>". Your mapping will not work since you will call `map` on `searcResultLiveData` but once you change the search term your search result live data MUST be changed, you will need to also update the mapped live data.

Comment: @HariKiran In real world you will meet the situation from other perspective. You will create a live data for some object `X` - lets call it `val liveX: LiveData<X>`. And then you will need to keep a live data object `Y` which depends on `X`: `val liveY: LiveData<Y>`. It will be logical to implement a map: `val liveY = liveX.map {...}`. Then you will start coding the mapping function in `{...}` and bam! you realize that in you mapping function you HAVE to call a third-party function (like DB call) which returns live data! Then you have no other choice but to use `switchMap` instead of `map`.

Answer (score 23):

**Map()**  is conceptually identical to the use in RXJava, basically you are changing a parameter of LiveData in another one
[image]

**SwitchMap()** instead you are going to substitute the LiveData itself with another one! Typical case is when you retrieve some data from a Repository for instance and to "eliminate" the previous LiveData (to garbage collect, to make it more efficient the memory usually) you pass a **new** LiveData that execute the same action( getting a query for instance)

Comment: by far, the only answer that reflects reality with an original straightforward example

Answer (score 9):

switchMap :
Let’s say we’re looking for the username Alice. The repository is creating a new instance of that User LiveData class and after that, we display the users. After some time we need to look for the username Bob there’s the repository creates a new instance of LiveData and our UI subscribes to that LiveData. So at this moment, our UI subscribes to two instances of LiveData because we never remove the previous one. So it means whenever our repository changes the user’s data it sends two times subscription. Now, how do we solve this problem…?

What we actually need is a mechanism that allows us to stop observing from the previous source whenever we want to observe a new one. In order to this, we would use switchMap. Under the hood, switchMap uses the MediatorLiveData that removes the initial source whenever the new source is added. In short, it does all the mechanism removing and adding a new Observer for us.

but map is static it used when you don't forced to get new live data every time

Comment: I came to this question from time to time and could not quite fully understand the answers (not just this one) until I am facing the problem explained here.

Answer (score 6):

- With `map` you have **same source livedata** in the end but it's data (value) changes with provided function before emitting
- With `switchMap`, you use source livedata just **as a trigger** for returning a standalone livedata (of course you can use triggers data in your function input)
- Trigger: everything that causes livedata's observer's `onChanged()` invoking

Answer (score 2):

### Transformation.map()

```
fun <X, Y> map(trigger: LiveData<X>, mapFunction: Function<X, Y> ): LiveData<Y>?
```

`trigger` - the LiveData variable that once changed triggers `mapFunction` to execute.

`mapFunction` - the function to call when a change take place on the `trigger` LiveData.  Parameter X is a reference to `trigger` (via `it`).  The function returns a result of specified type Y, which ultimately is returned by `map()` as a LiveData object.

Use `map()` when you want to perform an operation (via `mapFunction`) when the `trigger` LiveData variable changes.  `map()` will return a LiveData object that should be observed for the `mapFunction` to be called.

**Example:**

Assume a  simple list of bowler names, their average and their average with handicap:

```
data class Bowler(val name:String, val average:Int, var avgWHDCP:Int)
var bowlers = listOf<Bowler>(Bowler("Steve", 150,150), Bowler ("Tom", 210, 210))
```

Assume a `MutableLiveData` `Int` variable that holds a handicap increment value.  When this value changes, `avgWHDCP` for all bowlers in the list needs to be re-computed.  Initially it is set to zero.

```
var newHDCP:MutableLiveData<Int> = MutableLiveData(0)
```

Create a variable that calls `Tranformation.map()`.  It’s first argument is `newHDCP`.  It’s second argument is the function to be called when `newHDCP` changes.   In this example, the function will iterate through all the bowler objects, compute the new `avgWHDCP` for each bowler in the bowlers list, and return the result as an observable list of LiveData Bowler objects.  Note that in this example, the original non-LiveData list of bowlers and the returned list of bowlers  will reflect the same value, as they are referencing the same data store.  However,  the result of the function is observable.  The original list of bowlers is not as it was not setup as a LiveData.

```
var updatedBowlers: LiveData<List<Bowler>> = Transformations.map(newHDCP) {
    bowlers.forEach { bowler ->
        bowler.avgWHDCP  = bowler.average +  it
    }
    return@map bowlers
}
```

Somewhere in your code, add a method to update `newHDCP`.  In my example, when a radio button is clicked, `newHDCP` will get changed, and the process will trigger to call the function specified in `Transformations.map()`

```
rbUpdateBy20.setOnCheckedChangeListener { _, isChecked ->
        viewModel.bowlingBallObject.newHDCP.value = 20
}
```

Finally, all this will only work if `updatedBowlers` is observed.  This would be placed in your Activity or Fragment in a method such as `OnViewCreated()`

```
viewModel.updatedBowlers.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { bowler ->
    if (viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycle.currentState == Lifecycle.State.RESUMED) {
        refreshRecycler()
    }
})
```

If you wanted to get a little more concise and you really didn’t need a live reference to `updatedBowlers`, here’s how you can combine `updateBowlers` with the observer:

```
Transformations.map(viewModel.newHDCP) {
    viewModel.bowlers.forEach { bowler ->
        bowler.avgWHDCP  = bowler.average +  it
    }
    return@map viewModel.bowlers
}.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { bowler ->
    if (viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycle.currentState == Lifecycle.State.RESUMED) {
        refreshRecycler()
    }
})
```

And that’s basically it.  Anytime you change the value of `newHDCP`, the function specified in `Transformation.map()` will get called, it will transform the bowler object with the newly computed `avgWHDCP` and return a LiveData object of `List<Bowler>`

### Transformation.switchMap()

```
fun <X, Y> switchMap(source: LiveData<X>, switchMapFunction: Function<X, LiveData<Y>!>): LiveData<Y>
```

`source` - the LiveData variable that once changes triggers `switchMapFunction` to execute.

`switchMapFunction` - the function to call when a change take place on the source LiveData.  Parameter X is reference to the same source object (via `it`).  The `switchMapFunction` function MUST returns a LiveData result, which effectively gets returned via `Transformation.switchMap()`.  In essence, this allows you to swap out one reference of a LiveData container object for another.

Use `switchMap()` when you have a variable referencing a LiveData object, and you want to switch that variable to another, or to say it a different way you want to refresh the existing LiveData container.  This is useful, for example, if your LiveData variable is referencing a database data store and you want to requery with different parameters.  `switchMap` allows you to re-execute the query and replace with a new LiveData results.

**Example**:

Assume a database repository with a bunch of bowling ball queries from a BowlingBall DAO table:

```
private val repository  = BowlingBallRepository(application)
```

And I want to execute a query that fetches active or inactive bowling balls, depending on what the user specifies.  Through the UI, the user can select active or inactive, so my query needs to handle both. So I create a `MutableLiveData` variable that hold an active or inactive status.  In this example, I default to ‘A’ for active.

```
var activeFlag:MutableLiveData<String> = MutableLiveData(“A”)
```

Now, we need a LiveData variable that will hold the result of my query to get all the bowling balls of a specific status.  So I create a variable called `allBowlingBalls` of type `LiveData<List<BowlingBallTable>>?` and assign it to `Transformation.switchMap`.  I pass to the `switchMap` function the `activeFlag` variable as well as a lambda function that will receive that same `activeFlag` variable (via `it`) and the function makes a call to a query in the DB repository to re-fetch all bowling balls with the passed status.  The LiveData result of the lambda function passes back through the `switchMap` method and is re-assigned to `allBowlingBalls`.

```
private var allBowlingBalls: LiveData<List<BowlingBallTable>>? = Transformations.switchMap(activeFlag) {repository.getAllBalls(it)}
```

I need a way to trigger a refresh of `allBowlibgBalls`.  Again, this will be done when `activeFlag` changes.  Somewhere in your code, add a function to update `activeFlag`.  In my example, when a radio button is clicked, `activeFlag` will get changed, and the process will trigger to call the function specified in `Transformations.switchMap()`

```
rbActive.setOnCheckedChangeListener { _, isChecked ->
    if (isChecked) {
        viewModel.activeFlag.value = ActiveInactive.ACTIVE.flag
        refreshRecycler()
    }
}
```

Finally, all this will only work if allBowlingBalls is observed.  So first create a function to fetch allBowlingBalls:

```
fun getAllBowlingBalls():LiveData<List<BowlingBallTable>>? {
    return  allBowlingBalls
}
```

Then place an observer on `getAllBowlingBalls()`:

```
viewModel.getAllBowlingBalls()?.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { balls ->
    if (viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycle.currentState == Lifecycle.State.RESUMED) {
        refreshRecycler()
    }
})
```

And that’s it’s it.  Every time `activeFlag` changes, `allBowlingBalls` will be refreshed with a call to the repository and the `onChange` event of the observer on `allBowlingBalls` will trigger.  A simple technique for essentially building a dynamic search engine.

Answer (score 2):

Let me explain what I understood with an example. Consider a student data class

```
data class Student(val name: String, val marks: Int)
```

### **Transformation.map()**

Transforms the value of LiveData into another. It takes the value, applies the Function on the value, and sets the Function’s output as a value on the LiveData it returns. Here’s a example of how this can be used for the above data class:

```
 val student: LiveData<Student> = (get liveData<Student> from DB or network call)
 val studentName: LiveData<String> = Transformations.map(student) {it.name}
```

Here we get a student LiveData from a network or DB and then we take the value from the LiveData which is the Student object and just get the name of the student and maps it to another LiveData.

### **Transformation.switchMap()**

Transforms the value of a LiveData into another LiveData. Consider we want to implement a search feature for Students. Every time the search text changes we want to update search results. The following code shows how that works.

```
val searchQuery: LiveData<String> = ...

val searchResults: LiveData<List<Student>> = 
    Transformations.switchMap(searchQuery) { getSearchResults(it) }

fun getSearchResults(query: String): LiveData<List<Student>> = (get liveData<List<Student>> from DB or network call)
```

So here every time there is a new value in searchQuery, getSearchResults will be called with a new search query and searchResults will be updated.

Comment: Can you explain why in the use case of searching for Students cannot use Transformation.map(). What will be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

They have different Use case:

if you have a source LiveData and you just want to change the value inside that LiveData into some other data type, use `map`

If you have a source LiveData and a function that return a LiveData, and you want to create a LiveData that updates value base on the LiveData returned by that function. Use `switchMap`

Analyzing the source code, we see both `switchmap` and `map` return a new instance of MediatorLiveData.

`map` takes in a function that **return a new value for that MediatorLiveData** while `switchmap` **takes in a function that return a new instance of LiveData** (and then if the value of that new instance of LiveData change, use that to update MediatorLiveData's value)

in another word, `switchmap`'s LiveData value change if that input function's LiveData value change, `switchmap` also have the added benefit of unregistering the previous LiveData return from that input function.

Answer (score 0):

In short, the naming is analogous to rx map/switchMap.

Map is 1 to 1 mapping which is easy to understand.

SwitchMap on the other hand only mapping the most recent value at a time to reduce unnecessary compute.

Hope this short version of answer can solve everyone's problem easily.

Answer (score 0):

To my experience, both are to build a **bridge** with what you update (livedata #1) and what you really care/observe (livedata #2) in return. This bridge is necessary so that you can carry the lifecycle of the observer (i.e. your fragment) down to view models and they then can drop the subscription on all the `LiveData` involved in **automatically**. This is one of the main promises of `LiveData` from the beginning. So, this will keep that promise.

In case of `switchMap` the bridge is **dynamic** meaning there's always a **new** `LiveData` returned from the function (the lambda) - so you switch to this new `LiveData`. With `map` it's static.

I hope it helps a bit.

Answer (score 0):

using **switch map** to 1- **store** objects in **mutableLive** data and .if you want to **replace** this object with another object and **switch** between them in the **same** mutable live data to make some **operation** and **query** on it, it has good benefits when you make search function.

Answer (score 0):

To see the difference between those 2 methods, the most straightforward way is to go through the source code:

```
public inline fun <X, Y> LiveData<X>.map(crossinline transform: (X) -> Y): LiveData<Y> =
    Transformations.map(this) { transform(it) }


public inline fun <X, Y> LiveData<X>.switchMap(crossinline transform: (X) -> LiveData<Y>): LiveData<Y> = 
        Transformations.switchMap(this) { transform(it) }
```

From here we know the difference is in the `transform` function passed as the only parameter: for `map` it returns `Y` and for `switchMap` it returns `LiveData<Y>`.

Then we dive deeper into `Transformations.map` and `Transformations.switchMap`:

```
public static <X, Y> LiveData<Y> map(
        @NonNull LiveData<X> source,
        @NonNull final Function<X, Y> mapFunction) {
    final MediatorLiveData<Y> result = new MediatorLiveData<>();
    result.addSource(source, new Observer<X>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(@Nullable X x) {
            result.setValue(mapFunction.apply(x));
        }
    });
    return result;
}

public static <X, Y> LiveData<Y> switchMap(
        @NonNull LiveData<X> source,
        @NonNull final Function<X, LiveData<Y>> switchMapFunction) {
    final MediatorLiveData<Y> result = new MediatorLiveData<>();
    result.addSource(source, new Observer<X>() {
        LiveData<Y> mSource;

        @Override
        public void onChanged(@Nullable X x) {
            LiveData<Y> newLiveData = switchMapFunction.apply(x);
            if (mSource == newLiveData) {
                return;
            }
            if (mSource != null) {
                result.removeSource(mSource);
            }
            mSource = newLiveData;
            if (mSource != null) {
                result.addSource(mSource, new Observer<Y>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onChanged(@Nullable Y y) {
                        result.setValue(y);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
    return result;
}
```

Those 2 methods all return a newly created `MediatorLiveData`, but they are listening to different sources. For `map`, the `MediatorLiveData` simply listens to the original liveData. However, for `switchMap`, it listens to a new liveData created by `switchMapFunction`, which is the `transform` function in the previous call stack.

So it should be very clear now that `map()` and `switchMap()` of LiveData return a new `MediatorLiveData` which listens to different source `LiveData`s.

Answer (score 0):

Read carefully the source code examples before your read the answers here

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/Transformations#switchmap

Answer (score -1):

Here is a brief

If you are expecting the result value to change repeatedly use **swithMap()**
and if it is just one time operation use **map()** instead  .

Example : If you want to show scores of a live game use swithMap() .
If you want to show list of player of a team use map()