# How and where to use Transformations.switchMap?

Tags: android, android-architecture-components, android-livedata

In recent Android Architecture Components library released by Google, we have two static functions in the `Transformations` class. While the `map` function is straight forward and easily understandable, I am finding it hard to properly understand the `switchMap` function.

The official documentation of switchMap can be found [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/Transformations.html#switchMap(android.arch.lifecycle.LiveData%3CX%3E,%20android.arch.core.util.Function%3CX,%20android.arch.lifecycle.LiveData%3CY%3E%3E)).

Can somebody explain how and where to use the switchMap function with a practical example?

Comment: See also [What is the difference between map() and switchMap() methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47575961/what-is-the-difference-between-map-and-switchmap-methods). Maybe not a 100% duplicate but it has some very useful explanations

Answer (score 164, accepted):

In the `map()` function

```
LiveData userLiveData = ...;
LiveData userName = Transformations.map(userLiveData, user -> {
     return user.firstName + " " + user.lastName; // Returns String
});
```

everytime the value of `userLiveData` changes, `userName` will be updated too. Notice that we are returning a `String`.

In the `switchMap()` function:

```
MutableLiveData userIdLiveData = ...;
LiveData userLiveData = Transformations.switchMap(userIdLiveData, id ->
    repository.getUserById(id)); // Returns LiveData

void setUserId(String userId) {
     this.userIdLiveData.setValue(userId);
}
```

everytime the value of `userIdLiveData` changes, `repository.getUserById(id)` will be called, just like the map function. But `repository.getUserById(id)` returns a `LiveData`. So everytime that the value of the `LiveData` returned by `repository.getUserById(id)` changes, the value of `userLiveData` will change too. So the value of `userLiveData` will depend on changes of `userIdLiveData` and changes of the value of `repository.getUserById(id)`.

Practical example of `switchMap()`: imagine you have a user profile with a follow button and a next profile button which sets another profile info. Next profile button will call setUserId() with another id so `userLiveData` will change and UI will change. Follow button will call the DAO to add one follower more to that user, so the user will have 301 followers instead of 300. `userLiveData` will have this update that comes from the repository, which comes from the DAO.

Comment: so basically, it's a way to listen to a few change-sources of your data at once. If the id changes, your userLiveData changes, and if the values of the actual user changes, your userLiveData changes as well. Correct? (You could probably stack a few transformation together to connect even more LiveData's together, though you probably should use MediatorLiveData as well.)

Comment: Some architecture background of Transformations, they are most used at the ViewModel since it allows to transform the data of the type coming from the DAO to a type that needs to be shown at the UI, so, imagine you have an add to cart feature, you will be adding elements to a cart , lets say this cart is a hashmap that corresponds each product id with an item in a list, this hashmap comes from the DAO, but instead of passing this hashmap to the UI, we use a transformation to convert this hashmap into a friendly list to show in the UI, now HashMap<String,Cart> will be transformed as List<Cart>

Comment: Is this a good example? It seems to imply that you make a database call in the  `switchMap` callback, while the doc states: "The given function `func` will be executed on the main thread. "

Comment: How to set default value for transformations query?

Comment: Maarten, we should only return the userLiveData for observing and along with that do actual async call to the database and then call postValue on this livedata.

Comment: This example is actually a red herring... the value of switchMap() is in handling asynchronous updates - the LiveData returned by Transformations.switchMap() delegates to another, internal LiveData publisher within the switchMap implementation. This internal LiveData publisher is recreated / resubscribed to on every update. Essentially it makes it so that you will only ever receive the most recently triggered update, and previous updates will be unsubscribed to - but note that this mechanism does not guarantee synchronization with the system to which you're sending the updates!

Comment: So if we all just naively used switchMap() every time we were observing a repos LiveData, as the post suggests, we could be unknowingly introducing synchronization problems with our backend systems - any time multiple updates get sent and the backend system isn't guaranteed to handle them in a particular order, or we're sending requests on a background thread, we could fall out of sync with it. So in such cases switchMap() should only be used to observe stateless systems or in cases where state isn't being mutated. Also note it will cause the UI to drive the application state, not the service.

Answer (score 34):

Adding my 2 cents to @DamiaFuentes answer.

```
MutableLiveData userIdLiveData = ...;
LiveData userLiveData = Transformations.switchMap(userIdLiveData, id ->
repository.getUserById(id)); // Returns LiveData

void setUserId(String userId) {
     this.userIdLiveData.setValue(userId);
}
```

Transformations.switchMap method will only be called when you have at least one observer for userLiveData

Comment: Thanks a ton @Prakash i was struggling to find out why my switchMap was not listening to the changes in trigger.

Comment: I used to be a simple man. When I couldn't understand this concept, I went and made something of my own. In this case, I created a whole class with custom DataSource, builders, etc until I hit a mental block. Your answer made be a simple man again. I deleted that class.

Comment: repository.getUserById(id); How do you handle the case when switchmap() is called on the getUserById(), the mutabledata != null condition

Answer (score 30):

For those who want more explanation of @DamiaFuentes switchmap() function example given below:

```
 MutableLiveData userIdLiveData = ...;
 LiveData userLiveData = Transformations.switchMap(userIdLiveData, id ->
     repository.getUserById(id));

 void setUserId(String userId) {
      this.userIdLiveData.setValue(userId);
 }
```

In a scenario where the repository contains User(1, "Jane") and User(2, "John"), when the userIdLiveData value is set to "1", the switchMap will call getUser(1), that will return a LiveData containing the value User(1, "Jane"). So now, the userLiveData will emit User(1, "Jane"). When the user in the repository gets updated to User(1, "Sarah"), the userLiveData gets automatically notified and will emit User(1, "Sarah").

When the setUserId method is called with userId = "2", the value of the userIdLiveData changes and automatically triggers a request for getting the user with id "2" from the repository. So, the userLiveData emits User(2, "John"). The LiveData returned by repository.getUserById(1) is removed as a source.

From this example, we can understand that the userIdLiveData is the trigger and the LiveData returned by the repository.getUserById is the "backing" LiveData.

For more reference, check out: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/Transformations

Comment: Arch is deprecated: Use this https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/Transformations

Comment: How to set default query for the search string in switchmap?

Answer (score 5):

The function passed to switchMap returns LiveData. Use it when your repository itself returns LiveData.

Answer (score 4):

Another point to consider whether choosing between `switchMap` or `map`, you have to remember that `map` always wraps the returned value around `LiveData` e.g.

```
fun getUser(id: Int): User 
...
val userId = MutableLiveData(1)
val user = userId.map { // LiveData<User>
   repository.getUser(it)
}
```

You might consider using `map` if `repository.getUser(it)` returns a plain simple `User` object instead of `LiveData` so the type of user becomes `LiveData<User>`.

If `repository.getUser(it)` returns a `LiveData<User>` then it's better to use `switchMap`

```
fun getUser(id: Int): LiveData<User>
...
val userId = MutableLiveData(1)
val user = userId.switchMap { // LiveData<User>
   repository.getUser(it)
}
```

The `user` type would be `LiveData<User>`

Comment: This is pretty much same as `Optional.map()` and `Optional.flatMap()` in Java. It unwraps the `T` from `Optional<T>` to avoid having `Optional<Optional<T>>` in output. Same with LiveData, this `LiveData<LiveData<User>>` is nonsense.

Answer (score 3):

And yet another point for understanding.
One may think that as we always return new value (new reference) of LiveData inside switchMap() so how can we observe actual values with the observer having set just one time?
The point is the returned value of Transformations.switchMap is MediatorLiveData which adds new LiveData reference to as a new source (and deactivates the other sources).

Comment: You read my mind, thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Since Transformations are lazily calculated and behave in a lifecycle aware manner they can be used within the ViewModel, in combination with domain-level LiveData publishers, for publishing UI updates.

So switchmap is designed for dealing with asynchronous events. Lets say you're querying a database - an asynchronous operation - and publishing the results via LiveData in the manner described above. Lets say your application makes 2 queries in quick succession - query 1 returning response 1 (used to update the UI), and query 2 returning response 2. And let's say that although you sent query 1 first, it completes and arrives after query 2. With the regular Transformations.map() operator response 1 will be published last, and will determine the final application state. With Transformations.switchMap() the moment you send query 2 the first response will be effectively unsubscribed to, and you will only receive the second response. The way this works is the LiveData returned by Transformations.switchMap() delegates to another, internal LiveData publisher within the switchMap implementation. This internal LiveData publisher is recreated / resubscribed to on every update. But note that this wouldn't guarantee synchronization with the database in this example. You'd still receive response number 1 from the database... you just wouldn't be listening to it.

So this would only really be useful in cases where the request you’re sending is non-mutating, the UI is intended to drive the application state, and the service you're interacting with can't guarantee ordering of processing the updates (or maybe you're sending the request on a background thread).

The docs give an example of this here, where the user is inputting an address and a service is returning a zipcode. The user input is what should drive the application state here, so synchronization with the backend service isn't an issue - and the service is non mutating:
https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata

note that if you were to just naively use switchMap() and send requests to a service on a background thread... you could end up sending these requests in any order, and they could be processed in any order, but you'd still only ever receive the second response on the client... resulting in your client falling out of sync with your service.

In general I think it is better to just use Flows in the domain layer.
The accepted answer doesn't make this clear or accurately answer the question here, unfortunately.