# I can't share variables between two repositories using mvvm

Tags: java, android, api, mvvm, retrofit

I need to share two variables between two repositories. I've already tried many different solutions, but none worked. In short: first repository contain user last known location (geographical latitude and longitude) second repository calling the api with specified endpoints, such as geographical latitude and longitude. The thing is I consantly receiving those values with equal to 0,0. Could you give me some hint how I should do it? One thing that I observerd is that, the whole program runs immediatly, while the location repository need a couple of seconds to actuall get the latitude and longitude. So the program just constantly calling the api with endpoints equal to 0,0 as I meantioned above.

**Location repository**

```
    public class LocationRepository {

    private double mLatitude, mLongitude;
    
    public void test(Application application) {
        FusedLocationProviderClient client = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(application.getApplicationContext());
        {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                    application.getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.INTERNET) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                    ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(application.getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                    ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(application.getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                client.getLastLocation().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Location location) {
                        mLongitude = location.getLongitude();
                        mLatitude = location.getLatitude();
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Forecast repository**

```
public MutableLiveData<ForecastModel> testCall() {
MutableLiveData<ForecastModel> data = new MutableLiveData<>();

mApi.test(mLatitude, mLongitude, "metric", API_KEY).enqueue(new Callback<ForecastModel>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<ForecastModel> call, Response<ForecastModel> response) {
        if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
            Log.i(TAG, "onResponse: " + response.code());
        }
        data.setValue(response.body());
    }
    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<ForecastModel> call, Throwable t) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onFailure: " + t.getMessage());
    }
});
return data;
}
```

**ViewModel**

```
private ForecastRepository mForecastRepository;
private LocationRepository mLocationRepository;

private MutableLiveData<ForecastModel> mForecastData;

public ForecastViewModel(@NonNull Application application) {
    super(application);
    mLocationRepository = new LocationRepository();
    mLocationRepository.test(application);

    mForecastRepository = new ForecastRepository();
    mForecastData = mForecastRepository.testCall();
}
```

Comment: How does **ForecaseRepository** accesses **mLatitude** and **mLongitude** variables of **LocationRepository**?

Comment: For now it doesn't. I've deleted everything that I tried to cleanup the code. I've tried already making variables static, sending those variables through methods, even as lists.

Comment: You need to use livedata/stateflow, and observe it inside forecast repo.

Comment: I thought you can't observe livedata in repositories.

Comment: You can observe it wherever you want. Just try to architect your code properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use two livadata in ViewModel and Transformation.switchMap() to track changes. Everytime mLocationData changes mForcastData will update too. If you don't know how switchMap works you can check it [How and where to use Transformations.switchMap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47610676/how-and-where-to-use-transformations-switchmap) .

Change your ViewModel and LocationRepository like this.

**ViewModel**

```
public class ForecastViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {

    private ForcastRepository mForecastRepository;
    private LocationRepostiory mLocationRepository;

    private LiveData<ForecastModel> mForecastData;
    private LiveData<LocationModel> mLocationData;

    public ForecastViewModel(@NonNull Application application) {
        super(application);
        mLocationRepository = new LocationRepostiory();
        mLocationRepository.test(application);
        mLocationData = mLocationRepository.getMutableLiveData();
        mForecastRepository = new ForcastRepository();

        mForecastData = Transformations.switchMap(mLocationData, location->
                mForecastRepository.testCall(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()));
    }

    public LiveData<ForecastModel> getmForecastData() {
        return mForecastData;
    }
}
```

**LocationRepository**

```
class LocationRepostiory {

private LocationModel mLocation;
private MutableLiveData<LocationModel> mutableLiveData = new MutableLiveData();

public void test(Application application) {
    FusedLocationProviderClient client = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(application.getApplicationContext());
    {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                application.getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.INTERNET) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(application.getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(application.getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            client.getLastLocation().addOnSuccessListener(location -> {
                mLocation = new LocationModel(location.getLongitude(),location.getLatitude());
                mutableLiveData.setValue(mLocation);
            });
        }
    }
}

public MutableLiveData<LocationModel> getMutableLiveData() {
    return mutableLiveData;
}
}
```

**Forcast Repository**

```
public MutableLiveData<ForecastModel> testCall(double mLatitude, double mLongitude ) {
MutableLiveData<ForecastModel> data = new MutableLiveData<>();

mApi.test(mLatitude, mLongitude, "metric", API_KEY).enqueue(new Callback<ForecastModel>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<ForecastModel> call, Response<ForecastModel> response) {
        if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
            Log.i(TAG, "onResponse: " + response.code());
        }
        data.setValue(response.body());
    }
    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<ForecastModel> call, Throwable t) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onFailure: " + t.getMessage());
    }
});
return data;
}
```

**LocationModel**

```
class LocationModel {
    private Double longitude, latitude;

    public LocationModel(Double longitude, Double latitude) {
        this.longitude = longitude;
        this.latitude = latitude;
    }

    public Double getLongitude() {
        return longitude;
    }

    public Double getLatitude() {
        return latitude;
    }
}
```

If you don't want to make an extra LocationModel class then you can send your location data as List or Arraylist as well. Just I prefer this one.

Edited: There were some mistakes that I have corrected. Now code is working. Logcat from testCall() Method in ForcastRepository D/TAG: testCall: 90.3993212,23.7793183

Comment: This wouldn't work. LocationRepository will return location object which at that point would be null. mLocation's value would remain null - it wont update when location is recieved.

Comment: Location wasn't null but there were some errors in the code. Now I have edited. please check again.

Comment: Everything works fine for now. The switchMap is pretty new topic for me. Thank you for help, much appreciate it.