# NgRx effects combined with RxJS operators

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx

Does anyone know why the `switchMap` operator is not working ?

I have tried to put second `map` operator instead and it worked but I am not getting why `switchMap` is not working.

```js
    @Injectable()
    export class PizzasEffects {
        constructor(private actions: Actions, private pizzasService: PizzasService) {}

    @Effect()
        createPizzaSuccess$ = this.actions.ofType( fromPizzasActions.CREATE_PIZZA_SUCCESS ).pipe(
          map( (action: fromPizzasActions.CreatePizzaSuccess) => action.payload ),
          switchMap( (pizza: Pizza) => new  fromRouterActions.Go({path: ['products', pizza.id]}) ) 
        );
    }
```

Comment: `switchMap` expects an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable but you provide an `Action`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use simply `map` operator in place of `switchMap` as below :

```js
@Effect()
  createPizzaSuccess$ = this.actions.ofType(fromPizzasActions.CREATE_PIZZA_SUCCESS).pipe(
      map(action => action.payload),
      map(pizza => new fromRouterActions.Go({path: ['products', pizza.id]})) 
);
```

`switchMap` operator is expecting an `Observable`. For example, to return the result of a `HttpClient.get` :

```js
@Effect()
  createPizzaSuccess$ = this.actions.ofType(fromPizzasActions.CREATE_PIZZA_SUCCESS).pipe(
  map(action => action.payload),
  switchMap(pizza => this.httpClient.get(URL)) 
);
```

But in your case, value emitted is only an `Action`, so `map` operator is the correct choice, exactly like you did to extract `payload` from `action`.

Note also that `switchMap` is expecting a stream, and you can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.

It means, in the case of `NgRx`, it could be useful in certain situation, to return multiple actions for one `effect`, so an array of actions :

```js
@Effect()
  createPizzaSuccess$ = this.actions.ofType(fromPizzasActions.CREATE_PIZZA_SUCCESS).pipe(
  map(action => action.payload),
  switchMap(pizza => [
    new fromUIActions.showNotification({ message: 'Pizza loaded' }),
    new fromRouterActions.Go({path: ['products', pizza.id]})
  ]) 
);
```

More explanation :

- https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/switchmap
- [What is the difference between map() and switchMap() methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47575961/what-is-the-difference-between-map-and-switchmap-methods)

Comment: does it mean I could also just put the action into an array like this ?

  @Injectable()
    export class PizzasEffects {
        constructor(private actions: Actions, private pizzasService: PizzasService) {}

    @Effect()
        createPizzaSuccess$ = this.actions.ofType( fromPizzasActions.CREATE_PIZZA_SUCCESS ).pipe(
          map( (action: fromPizzasActions.CreatePizzaSuccess) => action.payload ),
          switchMap( (pizza: Pizza) => [new  fromRouterActions.Go({path: ['products', pizza.id]})] ) 
        );
    }

Comment: it means `switchMap(() => [x])` will have similar effect than `map(() => x)`, by emitting the unique value in array. but syntax of `map` is more clear in this case.

Comment: It's a pleasure, you're welcome on SO. However please take time to read https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers. Upvote is better than adding comment. Thanks.