# Can I use map instead of switchMap in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

The Code A is from the [artical](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/livedata-beyond-the-viewmodel-reactive-patterns-using-transformations-and-mediatorlivedata-fda520ba00b7) .

I think Code A can be converted to Code B, is it correct?

**Code A**

```
class MainViewModel {
    val repositoryResult = Transformations.switchMap(userManager.user) { user ->
        repository.getDataForUser(user)
  }
}
```

**Code B**

```
class MainViewModel {
    val repositoryResult = Transformations.map(userManager.user){ user->
       repository.getDataForUser(user) 
  }
}
```

**original Image**
[image]

Comment: Although there are some differences, but in your case both are same and you can use any

Comment: There is detailed answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47575961/what-is-the-difference-between-map-and-switchmap-methods