# Changing LiveData WHERE clause

Tags: android, android-room, android-livedata

I have a Room Dao method like this:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM stuff WHERE x == :y")
LiveData<List<Stuff>> getStuff(int y);
```

And in my ViewModel I have this variable:

```
LiveData<List<Stuff>> stuff = myDao.getStuff(7); // note the 7!
```

to observe it in my Fragment:

```
myViewModel.stuff.observe( // lalala...
```

So far so good, this is working well. However, at some point I want to change the data to be `stuff WHERE x == 8`.

If I were to simply `stuff = myDao.getStuff(8);`, my fragment would still observe the LiveData object `WHERE x == 7`.

If I would make `stuff` a MutableLiveData instead, I could update the data manually, but the updates from the database would still be for `WHERE x == 7` instead of 8.

Thus, how can I change what gets compared in the WHERE clause, update the data in LiveData correspondingly, have LiveData emit a corresponding event to its observers, and henceforth get updates only for the new value in the WHERE clause?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have come across Transfomations.switchMap, which does exactly what I've been looking for.

For it to work, the parameter to compare in the WHERE clause needs to be wrapped in LiveData:

```
final MutableLiveData<Integer> stuffParam = new MutableLiveData<>();
stuffParam.setValue(7);
```

with that, only one more line of code is necessary:

```
final LiveData<List<Stuff>> stuff = Transformations.switchMap(stuffParam, p -> myDao.getStuff(p));
```

Now making stuff hold the data `WHERE x == 8` is as simple as

```
stuffParam.setValue(8);
```

More information on Transformations:

[How and where to use Transformations.switchMap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47610676/how-and-where-to-use-transformations-switchmap)

[What is the difference between map() and switchMap() methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47575961/what-is-the-difference-between-map-and-switchmap-methods?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 1):

You have to do something like this in your `ViewModel`:

```kotlin
private val _stuff = MutableLiveData<List<Stuff>>(emptyList())
val stuff: LiveData<List<Stuff>>
    get() = _stuff

fun getStuff(x: Int) {
    _stuff = myDao.getStuff(x)
}
```

And in your fragment observe `stuff`.

Comment: I don't understand the syntax of the second and third line of your code. Is that an anonimous derived object?

Comment: This is a custom getter syntax in Kotlin https://kotlinlang.org/docs/properties.html#getters-and-setters